# Get Marker Open Linking Google Maps React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have this code

```js
openGps() {
    var url = 'geo:-8.4526503, 115.2353083';
    this.openExternalApp(url)
  }

  openExternalApp(url) {
    Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
      if (supported) {
        Linking.openURL(url);
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Eror Open Google Maps');
      }
    });
  }
```

When I click nothing marker appear

[image]

I wanna get marker in maps, anyone know URL to call?

How I get marker when call function openGps() in Android ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use

```
Linking.openURL(`https://maps.apple.com/?q=${markerName}&ll=${lat},${lng}`);
```

Comment: @AhmedAli For Android?

Answer (score -1):

```
const latLng = `${restaraunt.coordinate.latitude},${restaraunt.coordinate.longitude}`;
  
const mapQuery = restaraunt.title.split(' ').join('+');
 
const mapUrl = Platform.select({ ios: `http://maps.apple.com/?q=${mapQuery}&ssl${latLng}`, android: `geo:${latLng}?q=${mapQuery}` });
```

**UPD:**
Updating my answer:
*latLng* - it's just latitude & longitude, which i get from json data 
 *mapQuery* - simple string modifing for search query (tilte, in my case, it's name of restaraunt)
*mapUrl* - final url to open map in external app
and after all that, just using:

```
<MapView
            onPress={() => {
              Linking.canOpenURL(mapUrl).then(supported => {
                if (supported) {
                  Linking.openURL(mapUrl);
                } else {
                  console.log('Cant open')
                }
              }).catch(e => console.error(e))
            }}
```

Comment: you must explain your code